# How to build an ingress controller with central cert and auth management

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to expose a few webapps in EKS to the internet in a centrally managed secure way.

In AWS, using an ALB is nice, as it for example allows you to terminate TLS and add authentication using Cognito. ([see here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/how-to-use-application-load-balancer-and-amazon-cognito-to-authenticate-users-for-your-kubernetes-web-apps/))

To provision an ALB and connect it to the application there is the [aws-load-balancer-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller).
It works fine, but it requires for each and every app/ingress to configure a new ALB:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=test,Project=cognito
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: sample.${COK_MY_DOMAIN} 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: cognito
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-scope: openid
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-timeout: '3600'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-on-unauthenticated-request: authenticate
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-idp-cognito: '{"UserPoolArn": "$(aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id $COK_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --region $COK_AWS_REGION --query 'UserPool.Arn' --output text)","UserPoolClientId":"${COK_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID}","UserPoolDomain":"${COK_COGNITO_DOMAIN}.auth.${COK_AWS_REGION}.amazoncognito.com"}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: $COK_ACM_CERT_ARN 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: 'ip'
```

I would love to have one central well defined ALB and all the application do not need to care about this anymore.

My idea was having a regular [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and expose it via a central ALB.

Now the question is: **How do I connect the ALB to the nginx-controller?**

One way would be manually configuring the ALB and build the target group by hand, which does not feel like a stable solution.

Another way would be using aws-load-balancer-controller to connect the nginx. In that case however nginx seems not to be able to publish the correct loadbalancer address and external-dns will enter the wrong DNS records. (Unfortunately there seems to be no [--publish-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5231) option in usual ingress controllers like nginx or traefik.)

**Question:**

- Is there a way to make the nginx-ingress-controller provide the correct address?
- Is there maybe an easier way that combining two ingress controllers?

Comment: You can take a look at the [IngressGroup feature](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/76bd7e3fc59a3dffa28397db2991edfd1a5889c7/docs/guide/ingress/annotations.md#ingressgroup), which enables you to group multiple Ingress resources together. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: Since ALB can do path base routing etc, what's the need to have a secondary ingress-nginx in your cluster?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin I saw it but did not play with it. However it feels like it's very easy to mess that up. (Forgetting the annotation, having a typo, intentionally circumventing security, etc.) The idea was to make *sure* that all ingress traffic is secured out of the box.

Comment: @gohm'c Having a secondary ingress controller means that the second one needs to get the external address from the first one, which needs some kind of [--publish-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5231) option, which is not available in the usual ingress controllers like nginx or traefik. - If you are aware of an ingress controller being able to do so, I would be interested.

Comment: `...the second one needs to get the external address from the first one` - the 2nd one is ingress-nginx and the first one is aws alb? `external address` - you mean the actual client public ip or the aws alb ip?

Comment: @gohm'c Yes, nginx needs to publish the address of ALB. - See my own answer below. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a good solution.

I set up my environment using terraform.
After I set up the alb ingress controller, I can create a suitable ingress object, wait until the ALB is up, use terraform to extract the address of the ALB and use `publish-status-address` to tell nginx to publish exactly that address to all its ingresses:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "alb" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "alb"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    annotations = {
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme" = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports" = "[{\"HTTP\": 80}, {\"HTTPS\":443}]"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect" = "443"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn" = local.cert
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type" = "ip"
    }
  }
  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "alb"
    default_backend {
      service {
        name = "ing-nginx-ingress-nginx-controller"
        port {
          name = "http"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "ing-nginx" {
  name       = "ing-nginx"

  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace  = "kube-system"

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.type"
    value = "ClusterIP"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.publishService.enabled"
    value = "false"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.extraArgs.publish-status-address"
    value = kubernetes_ingress_v1.alb.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.config.use-forwarded-headers"
    value = "true"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.ingressClassResource.default"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

It is a bit weird, as it introduces something like a circular dependency, but the ingress simply waits until nginx is finally up and all is well.

This solution in not exactly the same as the [--publish-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5231) option as it will not be able to adapt to any changes of the ALB address. - Luckily I don't expect that address to change, so I'm fine with that solution.

Comment: Then, how do you manage auth types per Ingress resource/application ? Aren't you losing the key features of ALB Ingress like `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: cognito` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two ingress controllers. The ALB ingress controller will hand the publicly exposed endpoint and route traffic to the nginx ingress controller as its backend. Then you configure your nginx ingress controller for managing ingress of application traffic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The picture shows the regular "one controller" case. Having an nginx-controller behind an alb controller is exactly what I wrote in the question. The main issue with that is, that nginx will set an internal IP in the ingress status. Therefore external-dns will create an unusable DNS entry. Unfortunately there is no [--publish-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5231) option in nginx.